# organization won't appear in the Google Cloud Platform Console as a choice for migration

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to migrate an existing Google cloud project with no organization into an Organization. Google says that I should have a set of roles in the organization and project to achieve this as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing). As you can see in the screenshot below, I have all required roles added [image: roles]
Despite having all these roles in place, I still can't see the organization listed when I try to follow the steps to migrate the project to the organization as you can see below:
[image: Organization list]
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is fixed. I re-tried and it worked!